# Tkinter error on MacOS: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcbd5d9c1d0

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I'm developing an application in Python 3.7 with Tkinter (called "PyZHAireS.py). It works perfectly in Ubuntu and in Windows but when I sent it to my project tutor (who works with MacOS) appeared the error message that I show later.

It seems to be a library incompatibility, but I'm not fully sure about that. I show the scheme of the app with the libraries imported, if it were necessary to show any part of the code, please tell me in the comments section.

The app follows this type of scheme:

```
# Import part: ------------------------------

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from tkinter import font
import getpass
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# Start of the app: -------------------------

class Aplicacion():  
    def__init__(self):


    # (All application routines ...)



# End of the app: --------------------------

def main():
    mi_app = Aplicacion()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error message that appeared in the terminal was:

> 2019-07-26 10:55:24.750 python[8594:425628] -[NSApplication _setup:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcbd5d9c1d0
>
> 2019-07-26 10:55:24.756 python[8594:425628] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fcbd5d9c1d0'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff30e53ded
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 256
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff5cf1f720
>   objc_exception_throw + 48
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff30ed1195
>   -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
>
> 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff30df5a60
>   ***forwarding*** + 1486
>
> 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff30df5408
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>
> 5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010949b31d TkpInit +
>   413
>
> 6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001093f317e Initialize
>   + 2622
>
> 7   _tkinter.so                         0x000000010921ebe4 Tcl_AppInit
>   + 84
>
> 8   _tkinter.so                         0x000000010921e448
>   Tkinter_Create + 1128
>
> 9   libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b05494
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22980
>
> 10  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108aff874
>   PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2164
>
> 11  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a81503
>   function_call + 355
>
> 12  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 13  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a67df2
>   instancemethod_call + 162
>
> 14  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 15  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b095cf
>   PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 159
>
> 16  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a65d84
>   PyInstance_New + 148
>
> 17  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 18  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b05118
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22088
>
> 19  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108aff874
>   PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2164
>
> 20  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a81503
>   function_call + 355
>
> 21  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 22  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a67df2
>   instancemethod_call + 162
>
> 23  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 24  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b095cf
>   PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 159
>
> 25  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a65d84
>   PyInstance_New + 148
>
> 26  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108a589f5
>   PyObject_Call + 101
>
> 27  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b05118
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22088
>
> 28  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b09cb3
>   fast_function + 339
>
> 29  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b04f39
>   PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21609
>
> 30  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108aff874
>   PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2164
>
> 31  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108afeff2
>   PyEval_EvalCode + 34
>
> 32  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b2cacd
>   PyRun_FileExFlags + 157
>
> 33  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b2c610
>   PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 816
>
> 34  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x0000000108b434e2 Py_Main +
>   3506
>
> 35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5dfeded9 start + 1
>
> 36  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
>
> )
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>
> Abort trap: 6

Sorry if the error message is too long, I think it is necessary to put it.

Comment: Why are they running your Python 3.7 code in Python 2.7? I think that's a bug in TkInter that you can probably do nothing about

Comment: I'll check if they're running my code in Python 2.7 and, if it were the case, I will suggest them to update the Python version and write here the results obtained.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You could try adding this shebang to the top of the file, assuming you have python3 symlink: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`